# Ошибка импорта библиотеки requests в Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, sublime-text

Всем привет! Подскажите, как корректно подгрузить питоновскую библиотеку requests в ST3? Через pip3 (macOS) она установлена корректно, при вводе в Терминале  show и check выдает, что все корректно.

```
$ pip3 check requests
No broken requirements found.
```

При этом при попытке запустить код (установлен Sublime-REPL) выдает ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 4, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

Также установлен PyCharm, в нем запускается все корректно, без ошибок.

Comment: чем вас pycharm не устраивает?

Comment: Устраивает всем, но ST как-то легче и компактнее